# Send email on RazorSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, email, dbmail, razorsql

Is there any way to be able to send an email or some similar feature like with the `sp_send_dbmail` function in RazorSQL?

I was trying to look for similar functions or characteristics but I found zero information on this case

Comment: RazerSQL is a "query tool" according to the tag, not a database engine.

Comment: That said its the wrong place to send emails from anyway.